# jquery each function is not working with

Tags: jquery, html

**Question :**

I need to filter each letter in the paragraph tag using jquery each but it is not working .

**HTML**

```
  <p id="check">This is kamesh</p>
```

**jQuery**

```
var text = $(this).text(),
    jQuerytext = $(this) ,
    funtext ='' ,
    colorToggle = true;                                         
    $.each( text, function( key , value ){
      console.log(value);   //Value is empty                    
    });
```

I know the problem is in accessing the variable '**text**' but I can't able to sort it off ..
Thanks in advance

Comment: `text` is not an array, it's a string.

Comment: You are setting `text` to an array, then you are throwing out that array and replacing `text` with a string.

Comment: And actually, in this case, the value is not empty - it is a 'T'

Comment: Please stop using `alert()` for trouble-shooting. Spread the word.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: "Please stop using `alert()`" FIFY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to split out the text with empty character and then iterate the resultant array,

```
$.each( text.split(''), function( key , value ){
   alert(value);                 
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/T9YJE/)